# Inner join ignores identical values that have upper cases in one list and lower cases in another

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

In PostgreSQL - upon attempting the following inner join - I realized that some of the entries that suppose to match - are failed to be matched(!) 
When I compared my two lists I found out that the ones that failed contained a mixture of numbers and lower cases in one list, while they were presented as numbers and upper cases in the other list. Specifically - values like C6orf70 and C9orf156, appeared in one list in this format, while in the other list appeared in the following format: C6ORF70 and C9ORF156
As a result the inner join ignore all such cases and did not perform any matching. 
Do you know how can I tell my inner join to ignore match cases when joining the two lists?...
I didn't have any problem to inner join 'normal' genes  such as: HSP6, POLL, etc... These were in the upper case format in both lists. 
Thanks a lot!

```
select t1.* ,bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_exp.bvi_lr_rvd
into Patient_bvi_p_exp
from
(select split_part(id4, '@', 3)genes,*
from patient_bvi_p) t1
inner join 
(select genename,bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_lr_rvd
from geneexpression17p) bvi_exp
on t1.genes=bvi_exp.genename
```

Comment: if its a lowercase matter just use the string function LOWER().. aka `on LOWER(t1.genes) = LOWER(bvi_exp.genename)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select t1.* ,bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_exp.bvi_lr_rvd
into Patient_bvi_p_exp
from
(select *, LOWER(split_part(id4, '@', 3) ) genes
from patient_bvi_p) t1
inner join 
(select LOWER(genename),bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_lr_rvd
from geneexpression17p) bvi_exp
on t1.genes=bvi_exp.genename
```

or this

```
select t1.* ,bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_exp.bvi_lr_rvd
into Patient_bvi_p_exp
from
(select *, split_part(id4, '@', 3)genes
from patient_bvi_p) t1
inner join 
(select genename,bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_lr_rvd
from geneexpression17p) bvi_exp
on LOWER(t1.genes)=LOWER(bvi_exp.genename)
```

Comment: @rofls well if the OP would post some relevant data I can test it to ensure it works :)

Comment: if he ever comes back to the site, he'll have a solution :)

Comment: @rofls I dont think it matters if you have the LOWER on the join condition or inside the select since in either case the same string is being used.. but I would have to test to be sure

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the `t1.genes` and `bvi_exp.genename` as lower case during your join you should be fine:

```
select t1.* ,bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_exp.bvi_lr_rvd
into Patient_bvi_p_exp
from
(select split_part(id4, '@', 3)genes,*
from patient_bvi_p) t1
inner join 
(select genename,bvi_d_exp,bvi_r_exp,bvi_lr_rvd
from geneexpression17p) bvi_exp
on lower(t1.genes)=lower(bvi_exp.genename)
```

Comment: pretty easy to copy my comment

Comment: I was in the process of writing that sorry. I know SQL too, sir. Unlike the guy above who appears to have copied both of us.. :/ haha

Comment: I also don't typically look to see if there's a comment before posting an answer.